# How to assert if KeyPressEvent was any keyboard character?

Tags: java, gwt, keypress, keyevent

I want to assert a `com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent`. It should match any characters or digits, and signs like ,.-+~ etc.
Especially I want to exclude all "navigation" keys like arrows, insert, delete, pos1, end, F1-12 etc.

Why does the following not work?

```
KeyPressEvent keyEvent;
if (Character.isLetterOrDigit((int) keyEvent.getUnicodeCharCode()) {}
```

Result:

> The method isLetterOrDigit(char) in the type Character is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: WTF is a `KeyPressEvent`?  I don't see it in J2SE.

Comment: Are you using a version of java pre 1.5?  isLetterOrDigit only allowed you to accept an int from 1.5 and beyond.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. Did not notice that it is gwt specific class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Character.isLetterOrDigit(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit%28int%29) is only supported in Java 1.5 or newer. You may be using an older version.

Try casting to a `char` instead to match the method signature:

```
Character.isLetterOrDigit((char)keyEvent.getUnicodeCharCode())
```

Comment: This is GWT [KeyPressEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyPressEvent.html#getUnicodeCharCode()) :)

Comment: my bad, didn't catch changes, aaach initianally there was awt tag :-) this is out of my knowledges .....

Comment: how do you consume() those events, sure there is dispatcher, but nothing betweents those two phaaa :-)

Comment: ty Reimeus, it works so far! @mKorbel: by the way I did not add the awt tag myself, must have been false added by a moderator.